# Maven multi-module, exec in one submodule only without using install

Tags: java, maven

Root of the project has two submodules `m1` and `m2` where `m1` depends on `m2`. I want to compile everything needed, and execute one class from m1. The submodule `m1` has the following profile in its pom.xml:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>traverse</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>traverse</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>java</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>-classpath</argument>
                            <argument>org.example1.MyModule1</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

However, when I invoke the command `mvn compile` and `mvn exec:exec -Ptraverse -pl m1` I got the following error from the root module:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project m1: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.example:m1:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.example:m2:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

I don't want to use `mvn install` and clutter my `.m2` folder. How can I run the above script without install?

Comment: would you mind being my beta-tester? https://github.com/andreybpanfilov/inter-module-helper I'm not sure about `mvn compile`, but `mvn package` should work.

Comment: Would you mind being an alpha tester for Maven-4? You can download it from https://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-4/ and IIRC it was required to solve https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4660

Comment: The first to check is if running `mvn package` works from the root module... if that's fine you go with the suggestion of Robert...